# Can't mount external drive on archlinux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, arch-linux

I have big problem with my external drive (500gb) I just try everything. I use archlinux and i have a I/O errors : (dmesg)

```
  224.116533] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 488383992
[  224.116545] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 488383993
[  224.116548] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 488383994
[  224.116550] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 488383995
```

ls -l /dev/sdb

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 10-26 18:35 /dev/sdb
```

When I plug disk on gentoo or windows everything is okey. That's anyone know how to repair this ?

Comment: "I just try everything" please show us some specific things you tried and how they fail. What errors do you get when attempting to mount?

Comment: Same pc (different boot), or different pc?

Comment: try running dmesg and check if it has bad sector errors. Then its a hardware problem. If you have important data, you can still get it out with ddrescue and an external drive. ddrescue to ISO and mount that iso afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This error is always associated with hardware failures, not software errors, but I have seen this error appear before

1. disk failures
2. USB system failures.

That's why I asked you whether the Fedora and Windows systems capable to read your data are on your pc (via dual boot or VM) or on different pcs. If we are talking about a different pc, then the most likely answer is your USB system (bus?).

In any case, I would suggest running a fsck on your disk from the Fedora system. I doubt this is possible from the Arch system, because if the OS cannot access the disk, then neither can the fsck utility.

After this check from Fedora, you will know which of the two alternatives above applies to your case.